# Puppet with apache and passenger: Could not spawn process for application

Tags: ruby, apache, puppet, passenger

I get the following error in apache log on puppet master:
Any ideas what could be wrong here:

```
[ E 2018-03-11 07:50:58.9057 10913/T8 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:285 ]: [Client 1-1] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is cd3585fe. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
App 10950 stdout: 
App 10950 stdout: 
[ E 2018-03-11 07:51:03.0922 10913/Te age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /usr/share/puppet/rack/puppetmasterd: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: 01cd04d1
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-sAcbhg.html
  Message from application: cannot load such file -- puppet/util/command_line (LoadError)
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  config.ru:32:in `block in <main>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/passenger-5.2.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `eval'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/passenger-5.2.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `preload_app'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/passenger-5.2.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/passenger-5.2.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/passenger-5.2.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

My config:
Centos 6.5,
Puppet 3.8.7,
Apache/2.2.15, 
Phusion Passenger 5.2.1

Comment: have you bundled all the gems for puppet correctly?

Comment: [root@puppetmaster modules]# gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (default: 1.3.0)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
did_you_mean (1.1.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.3.2)
io-console (default: 0.4.6)
json (default: 2.0.2)
minitest (5.10.1)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
openssl (default: 2.0.3)
passenger (5.2.1)
power_assert (0.4.1)
psych (default: 2.2.2)
rack (2.0.4)
rake (12.0.0)
rdoc (default: 5.0.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
test-unit (3.2.3)
xmlrpc (0.2.1)
But as puppet:  # sudo -u puppet gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

json (1.5.5)